# How to change domain / ip address of a Kinetica GPUDB Kagent and Gadmin instance after it is deployed?

Tags: tomcat, kinetica

I have a fresh Kinetica deployment that was super easy via Kagent GUI on a new VM. The domain I used is no longer available, so I wanted to change it back to a local ip address.

I was able to change the domain to an ip address in `gpudb.conf` under `/opt/gpudb/core/etc/` as outlined in the docs [here](https://www.kinetica.com/docs/config/index.html#network), but I am getting errors in gadmin in the SQL query window that is pointing to the old domain still. The domain has to be set somewhere else in the configuration files, but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the domain that is set initially during first deploy via Kagent or for a manual install is set inside Tomcat configuration files at `/opt/gpudb/tomcat/webapps/gadmin/WEB-INF/classes/gaia.properties`. Once you change this to whatever new value you want, then `sudo /etc/init.d/gpudb restart all`, everything works fine again.